# JavaScript Map Function Passing Object to another Function in Template Literal

Tags: javascript

I have the following function where I am iterating through an array using the map function. I want pass the ticket object to a sendTicketToArchive function. The code below throws an exception saying that this is not possible and object is undefined. How can I achieve it?

```
function updateUI(allTickets) {    
    let allTicketsAttributes = allTickets.map((ticket,index) => {
        return `
                <div class="ticket">
                    Subject: ${ticket.Subject}
                    <p>Submitted at: ${ticket.Date}</p>
                    <p>Priority: ${ticket.Priority}</p>
                    <p>Description: ${ticket.Description}</p>
                    <div id="ticketButtons">
                        <button onclick='cancelTicket("${ticket.ticketId}")'>Cancel</button>
                        <button onclick='sendTicketToArchive(${ticket})'>Remove</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
               `
    })
        allTicketsUL.innerHTML = allTicketsAttributes.join('')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are building a string, so you need to stringify the object so it could be properly passed to the `sendTicketToArchive()` function. Try with this example: (it's your code but a bit modified, I used `JSON.stringify()`)

```js
function updateUI(allTickets) {    
    let allTicketsAttributes = allTickets.map((ticket,index) => {
        return `
                <div class="ticket">
                    Subject: ${ticket.Subject}
                    <p>Submitted at: ${ticket.Date}</p>
                    <p>Priority: ${ticket.Priority}</p>
                    <p>Description: ${ticket.Description}</p>
                    <div id="ticketButtons">
                        <button onclick='cancelTicket("${ticket.ticketId}")'>Cancel</button>
                        <button onclick='sendTicketToArchive(${JSON.stringify(ticket)})'>Remove</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
               `
    });
    console.log(allTicketsAttributes.join(''));
}

updateUI([
  {Subject: 'sub1', Date: 'date1', Priority: 'prio1', Description: 'desc1', ticketId: 1},
  {Subject: 'sub2', Date: 'date2', Priority: 'prio2', Description: 'desc2', ticketId: 2}
]);
```

Comment: One problem can be occured - it will be new object, not a reference to existing, so if inside function this object will be changed - it will not reflect allTickets

Comment: True that. However, the OP did not mention if he cares about references so for now I think both solutions are OK

Answer (score 1):

This way you just send ticket.toString, there should be the name of variable which is globally available, for example

```
let allTicketsGlobal
function updateUI(allTickets) {    
  allTicketsGlobal = allTickets    
  let allTicketsAttributes = allTickets.map((ticket,index) => {
...
<button onclick='sendTicketToArchive(allTicketsGlobal[${index}])'>Remove</button>
```